# Serializing the current state of "Module Random" in OCaml's StdLib

Tags: serialization, random, ocaml, standard-library

I must have read the OCaml manual page on the standard library modules `Random` and `Random.State` half a dozen times (probably even more often) but I can't figure out how to serialize the current internal state of the PRNG.

Here's what I learned so far:

- The modules `Random` and `Random.State` both operate on a state that is abstract / opaque from the outside.
- Both modules offer two / three initializers, but functions exporting the current state ... I can't see them :(

What can I do ? Help please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize (and de-serialize) the state using the [Marshal](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Marshal.html) module, e.g.,

```
let save_random_state out = 
   Marshal.to_channel out (Random.get_state ()) []

let load_random_state inp = 
   Random.set_state (Marshal.from_channel inp)
```

But if you just want the `Random` module to generate the same sequences of pseudo-random numbers than it is better just to initialize with the same state, i.e., use the same seed, e.g., if you will start your program with,

```
let () = Random.set_state (Random.State.make [|42|])
```

you will get the deterministic behavior of your program, as the `Random` module will always generate the same numbers.

Comment: Seeding during init is fine, but it does not enable the resumption of long-winding computation (when the initial UNIX process is long gone and a new one has been started up to finish some partially done work).

Comment: So the plan looks like `s |> Marshal.to_string |> Z.of_bits` to get that state into a Zarith big-integer. Quite a bit of work, but understandably so. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea. Again, if you just want to control the state then use `Random.set_state` and put your state there. If your state (aka seed) is represented as a Z.t number, then translate it to an array of bytes and use this array as the seed.

Comment: You are right! Going *from* a `Random.state` *to* a Z.t is not a good idea. Dynamic typing to the rescue:) My Prolog's `random:setrand/1` predicate will both Prolog atoms (for precisely representing `Random.State`s) and Prolog numbers (integer / floats); the first one enabling a exact reproduction of some former state, the latter ones for convenience (seeding with sub-second precision UNIX time). Thanks!

Comment: Btw. This is like SICStus Prolog does it. And a proverb among Prolog implementors goes like this: in cases of uncertainty do it like SICStus. Haha, only serious:)